# postgres table not populating from csv but no error returned

Tags: python, sql, pandas, postgresql, psycopg2

I'm experimenting with postgres, trying to populate a table with selected values from another table with a python script that converts CSVs to dataframes, cleans them, converts back to temporary csv to crawl for specific data points to populate the SQL table with. Everything seems to run with no issue. The dfs are cleaned properly and the script runs with no errors but the table is not being populated. Any idea what I'm doing wrong here? I've included the script below and an example of one of the CSVs I'm working with.

link to csv example (working w/ the first 8): https://ark-funds.com/download-fund-materials/

```
import config
import csv
import psycopg2
import psycopg2.extras
import pandas as pd
import glob

csv_path = r'/this/is/the/path/2022-05-28/*.csv'

connection = psycopg2.connect(host=config.host, database=config.db_name, user=config.my_db_un, password=config.my_db_pass)

cursor = connection.cursor(cursor_factory=psycopg2.extras.DictCursor)

cursor.execute("select * from stock where is_etf = TRUE")

etfs = cursor.fetchall()

current_date = ['2022-05-27']

for arks in glob.glob(csv_path):
    df=pd.read_csv(arks)
    df = df.replace(',','', regex=True)
    df = df.replace('%','', regex=True)
    df = df.replace('\$','', regex=True)
    df = df[:-1]
    print(df)
    tmp_df = "./tmp_dataframe.csv"
    df.to_csv(tmp_df, index_label='id', header=False)
    f = open(tmp_df, 'r')
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    next(reader)
    for row in reader:
        etf_id = row[1]

        ticker = row[3]

        if ticker: 
            shares = row[5]
            weight = row[7]

            cursor.execute("""
                SELECT * FROM stock WHERE symbol = %s
            """, (ticker,))
            stock = cursor.fetchone()
            if stock:
                cursor.execute("""
                    INSERT INTO etf_holding (etf_id, holding_id, dt, shares, weight)
                    VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)
                """, (etf_id, stock['id'], current_date, shares, weight))

    connection.commit()
```

Comment: The INSERT is dependent on some conditions being true:  `if ticker` and `if stock`.  Do you know that those conditions are, in fact, true?  Have you added `print()` statements that tell you whether those conditions are true?

Comment: and if select return no row, there is no insert

Comment: Have you looked at the Postgres log to see what is actually hitting the database?